# Double pointer array in c++

Tags: c++, c, arrays, allocation

I was reading a program about BTree, there I came across this : `BTreeNode **C`. I understand that it is a 2d array but it was initialized as `C=new BTreeNode *[2*t];`. I can't understand this: is this a 2d array with dynamic rows and 2t columns ?
Thanks.

Comment: `2t` is not valid syntax.

Comment: Sorry, it was 2*t, t is predefined value.

Comment: How is this question related to *digital signature algorithm*?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You probably well know that `double*` is a pointer to a `double` element. In the same way, `double**` is a pointer to a `double*` element, which is itself a pointer. Again, `double***` is a pointer to a `double**` element, and so on.

When you instanciate an array to a type `T`, you usually do `new T [size];`. For example, for an array of `double`, you write `new double[size];`. If your type `T` is a pointer itself, it's exactly the same : you write `new double*[size];`, and you get an array of pointers.

In your case, `BTreeNode*` is a pointer to `BTreeNode`, and `BTreeNode**` is a pointer to `BTreeNode*` which is a pointer to `BTreeNode`. When you instanciate it by doing `new BTreeNode*[size];` you get an array of pointers to `BTreeNode` elements.

But actually, at this step you don't have a 2D array, because the pointers in your freshly allocated array are NOT allocated. The usual way to do that is the following example :

```
int num_rows = 10;
int num_cols = 20;
BTreeNode** C = new BTreeNode*[num_rows];
for(int i = 0; i < num_rows; i++)
{
  // Then, the type of C[i] is BTreeNode*
  // It's a pointer to an element of type BTreeNode
  // This pointer not allocated yet, you have now to allocate it
  C[i] = new BTreeNode [num_cols];
}
```

Don't forget to delete your memory after usage. The usual way to do it is the following :

```
for(int i = 0; i < num_rows; i++)
  delete [] C[i];
delete [] C;
```

Comment: Not that there's anything _technically_ wrong with this, but I think "the usual way" is to use a `vector` and let that handle all the manual memory management cruft. I thought we were past end-users typing `new` and `delete`, but this pattern seems to crop up all the time. It seems more like a barely translated holdover from C than anything else. Whereas a `vector` of `vector`s would seem to achieve the same thing while not needing us always to remember to `new` and `delete` properly.

Comment: I not agree with you. First, the PO is reading an existing code, he's not writing something. Second, in some cases, it's clearly required, like for using blas and lapack libraries.

Comment: If the OP is not writing something, then why did you tell them how to write this? And sure, it can be required, but that's the exception rather than the rule; "the usual way" is different from "in some cases", after all. All I meant was the best recommendation is to use stdlib abstractions wherever possible, not manual memory management, unless you're an stdlib developer or have a proven need to do things manually. I mention this in case the OP _thinks_ they need `new`/`delete` but maybe don't.

Comment: To learn something more than the question ? But you can only answer striclty to questions if you want and let people do usual mistakes. Moreover, it's the usual way in a context of allocation with a `new`, yes.

Comment: For sure, if someone is already talking about `new`, it's always good to mention `delete`, since it often gets forgotten :-)

Answer (score 0):

The statement `C=new BTreeNode *[2*t];` allocates space for `2*t` instances of type `BTreeNode *` and therefore returns a type `BTreeNode **` pointing to the first element of such instances. This is the first dimension of your array, however no memory has been allocated for the second dimension.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. If the array is being indexed column-major order (so C[3][4] is the 5th element of the 4th column) then C could, potentially, have ragged (differently sized) columns.

Look for some code that allocates memory for each column, i.e.

```
C[i] = new BTreeNode[length];
```

in a loop over i, that would indicate that the 2D array has the same length per column.